# Fastest way to write binary files on drive

Tags: python, django

I take the files(images, audios or videos) from a `<input type="file">` and save them on a hard drive in a local server, here's the part of code I use:

```
direc = 'C:\\EXAMPLE\\FOLDER\\'
for fl in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
    filetow = open(direc + str(fl), 'wb+')
        for chunk in fl.chunks():
            filetow.write(chunk)
        filetow.close()
```

Is there a way to make the process of write files on hard drive faster?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Buy faster hardware.

Comment: If you have many files multiprocessing might help, writing more files at the same time.